# C/C++ programming about read/wri

Tags: c, memory, read-write

I am starting to figure out some basic ideas about memory reading and writing (let's assume that the data we read or write have not been cached yet).

For the following code:

```
int a = 1;
```

It's definitely a write, since we write the value '1' to the memory place of variable 'a'.

But for the following code:

```
int a, b;
a = 1;
b = a;
```

When we execute the statement "b = a;", do we actually perform one read and one write?
To my understandings, I think it's one read and one write, since we have to load the value of 'a' first and then write the value to 'b'.

Not sure if my understandings are correct. Please help me to clarify these basic ideas.
Many thanks for the help.

Comment: It isn't meaningful to think of high level C code as "reads" and "writes" or "this code must do x reads and y writes". That's not how it works - what matters is how that C code gets translated to machine code by the compiler, which is a big topic. If you wish to learn these things, you should study an assembler language.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's assume that the data we read or write have not been cached yet)

I don't see how cache is pertinent to this.

> When we execute the statement "b = a;", do we actually perform one read and one write?

Correct.

However, C is not like the assembly language. C instructions don't map 1-to-1 to machine instructions. There is [the as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). Basically the compiler can generate whatever machine code as long as the observable behavior of the program is preserved.

For instance:

```
auto foo()
{
    int a = 24;
    int b = 11;
    int c = a + b;

    return c;
}
```

C compiler is free to compile the above to

```
foo():
        mov     eax, 35
        ret
```

And compilers do actually do this (with optimizations enabled). As you can see there is no memory read/write. Just just a write to the `eax` register (where the return of the function must be put). And the value is an imediate (`35`).

Comment: Thanks, I do understand that optimization can somewhat change the behaviors of the compiler. Let's assume if there is no such optimization when compiling, we can assume that code ```b = a;``` is kind of one read and one write, right?  Also, I just found out that the website Compiler Explorer can help transform the C codes to Assembely ( check out this link: https://godbolt.org/z/8G13Ps ). So the read and write as we mentioned are just ```mov``` in Assembly, right?

Comment: @WentaoHuang, there's a difference between reads and writes to memory in the resulting machine code, and reads and writes to the (abstract) variables if the C program. They're not the same thing: in the above example the variables `a`, `b` and `c` don't even exist in the resulting machine code. As for that godbolt example, try adding `-O2` or `-O3` to the compiler options in the upper right...

Comment: "we can assume that code b = a; is kind of one read and one write, right"  No! You can't assume a thing of high level code. In this case it matters a lot where the compiler allocated those variables: in registers, on the stack or at dedicated memory addresses. Each of these 3 scenarios yield different code. For example the CPU might have to load the values into registers before storing them elsewhere.

Comment: @Lundin, so can we assume it is one load and one store?

Comment: @WentaoHuang "You can't assume a thing of high level code."